# My socket keeps closing after socket.connect times out

Tags: java, sockets

This is driving me insane!

I'm trying to implement TCP holepunching and as part of this I have a socket trying to connect continuously.

For some reason, after the first mobileSocket2.connect call times out, the second time a socket closed exception comes up. I have no idea why. As far as I can tell, a connection timeout shouldn't close the socket. so why does it say socket closed the second loop?

I bind a socket to the same local IP address and local port earlier on but close that socket.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Socket mobileSocket2 = new Socket();

        try {

        System.out.println("105");

        mobileSocket2.setReuseAddress(true);
        System.out.println("109");

        mobileSocket2.setSoTimeout(50);

        mobileSocket2.bind(new InetSocketAddress(myIPAddress.getHostAddress(), myPort));
        System.out.println("bound");

        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("caught 104: " + e.toString());
        }




    while(true){

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        try{

                System.out.println("124");
                mobileSocket2.connect(new InetSocketAddress(mobileAddress.getHostAddress(), mobilePort));
                System.out.println("connection made: " + mobileSocket);


            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("exception 2 caught " + e.toString());

            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is invalid.

1. You can't reconnect a connected `Socket.` When the connect succeeds you need to add a `break` statement.
2. You can't reuse a `Socket` when a `connect()` has failed. You have to close it and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Either reopen the socket when the first exception is caught, or set the timeout to 0, which the javadoc says it is interpreted as 'infinite'. I didn't look at the Socket and SocketImpl code, but I'm fairly confident that, since Socket is a Closeable (and also an AutoCloseable), the implementation is along the lines of

```
public void connect(InetAddress address, int port) throws IOException {
   try {
      // connect to the other endpoint
   } catch(/*any relevant exception*/) {
      throw new IOException(/* ... */);
   } finally {
      this.close();
   }
}
```